# Proving bijection of a function of the form f(x,y).

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by

$$f(x,y) = ((x^2+1)y, x^3)) $$

is bijective. I know that to prove a function is bijective we have to prove that is injective and surjective. The structure of this problem is confusing me and I am not sure how to approach this problem. I was thinking that I would set $X=(x^2+1)y$ and $Y=x^3$ and then solve for $x$ and $y$? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try and proceed as you would normally. Thus, for injectivity, assume $f(x,y) = f(x',y')$, and deduce $(x,y) = (x',y')$.

Comment: So, would I state that for 4 arbitrary real numbers (a,b,c,d), f(a,b)=f(c,d). Therefore, ((a^2+1)b,a^3)=((c^2+1)d,c^3)

Comment: Yes, you _suppose_ for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ ... etc. and then deduce $(a,b)=(c,d)$

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was making it harder than it needed to be.

Comment: TO prove that the function is surjective, I would have to find the inverse, but the function is an ordered pair. Would I set x=(x^2+1)y and y=x^3 and then find the inverses in that manner?

Comment: Almost. You don't have to find an explicit inverse function. Just assume we are given some $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and find $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(a,b) = (x,y)$.